# Unable to deploy challenge token for dehydrated

Tags: linux, centos, ssl-certificate

I have intalled dehydrated for Let's Encript certificate

There is an error message:

..............

- Handling authorization for example.com
- 1 pending challenge(s)
- Deploying challenge tokens...
  deploy_challenge: example.com, bWHUdPQ67v7-zGm7ndItbXY2Kwl0eAJ1U2ZQ_KMZKCI, BUNS861klFWAsb2peR5mB1HROuRpnhhv-ZBoMB6mB0o
  jq: error (at :1): Cannot index string with string "name"
  ERROR: deploy_challenge hook returned with non-zero exit

CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Server version: Apache/2.4.54

## These are some settings

/etc/dehydrated/config:

```
...
WELLKNOWN="/var/www/dehydrated"
HOOK="${BASEDIR}/hook.sh"
...
```

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
...
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge /var/www/dehydrated
<Directory /var/www/dehydrated>
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      Require all granted
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
...
```

I am trying to intall Let's Encrypt certificatebut unsuccessfully.